# Could not parse XML file from a path using python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

When I try to parse an xml file that is not in the same directory as my script I have this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Yac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
        tree.parse(source, parser)
      File "C:\Users\Yac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
        self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

This is my code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\Yac\Desktop\AAAAA\ABD\DATA.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `tree = ET.parse(“path/to/file.xml”)`
or 
`ET.fromstring(open(‘path/to/file.xml’).read())`

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue because I had provided the wrong path which did not contains xml files but txt files.